At what point does laravel eloquent execute a database query in this method chain?
I am working with Laravel Eloquent, and I am building a query with chained methods. I understand that some methods trigger the execution of a query while others simply build it. I have this method chain:
$tags = $user->tags()->where('tag', 'like', '%' . $tag . '%')
            ->whereNotIn('tag', $file_tags)
            ->pluck('tag')
            ->take(10)
            ->toArray(); 

I did't call get() at all, but i still get the result.
My question is:

At what point does the database query actually get executed in this chain? Is it at pluck(), take(), toArray(), or somewhere else? Did I correctly query only 10 items from the database, or did I just query the entire dataset and then tells php to return only 10?
Is pluck('tag') the same as select('tag'), or did it query select('*') and PHP processed it to return only the 'tag' column?


why don’t you install a debugger or simply output the raw sql generated after your method chaining to see what query has been executed!

so this is what happens in your code, when yo write where() and whereIn(), you are basically just building the query, the query get executed in pluck() and it returned all rows meeting condition in where() and whereIn(). take(10) just limiting 10 result from all query results. so to answer your question :

it is pluck() the one that trigger the execution of query. And if your intention is to only query 10 from database, you should move take(10) before pluck()
pluck() responsible in query execution, while select() only build the query. you should use get() or first() to trigger it. But on functionality it works the same, where they immediately execute queries to select on tag values

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/collections#method-pluck
